# Do you need to lubricate gears after cleaning gears and chain?

Tags: maintenance, chain, gears, lubricant

I just cleaned my gears and chain with a biodegradable degreaser. I'm going to lubricate my chain. Do I also need to lubricate the gears or do I just pedal and make sure that I hit all gears? Will the lube on the chain lube the gears?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to lubricate your gears since they don't have any moving parts or pivots (it's the hub that rotates). Cleaning them is all you needed to do.

Comment: Actually, some lubricant on the gears is beneficial because it will a) reduce friction between chaing & sprockets, and b) protect the sprockets from corrosion (to some degree). But usually the chain will "bleed" enough lubricant anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I always wash off the degreaser, lube the chain, and then run it through all gears to get a bit of lube worked into everything. Don't need to lube the gears specifically.

I think the key is to be sure to wash off all traces of the degreaser. Last thing you need is residual cleaner gunking stuff up.

Comment: How do you wash off all the degreaser? Soap and water and elbow grease?

Comment: I degrease (using one of those chain cleaning rigs - something [like this](http://www.mec.ca/Products/product_detail.jsp?PRODUCT%3C%3Eprd_id=845524441774255&FOLDER%3C%3Efolder_id=2534374302693915) ), and run the chain through all gears. Then, I use a brush to work grit free, and scrub everything clean with rags. Then, I rinse the crap out of everything with water. Seems to work well enough.